# Deriving the free streaming distance for HDM particles

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, neutrinos

I am trying to derive the free-streaming length for the HDM particles but I couldnt follow the arguments given by the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0201405v1.pdf after equation 83.

Thanks